# Match the SourceName set in nxlog in syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng, nxlog

This one is driving me a bit crazy. How do I route a message from nxlog received by syslog-ng based on the program name? It should be self explanatory but it isn't working correctly. The messages are dropped into my general log file for syslog-ng without the filtering applied.

I'm sending IIS logs like this with nxlog:

```
<Input W3SVC>
    Module im_file
    ...
    Exec $SourceName = 'IIS';
    ...
</Input>
<Route W3SVC>
    Path W3SVC => IIS_Syslog
</Route>
<Output IIS_Syslog>
   Module om_udp
   Host xxx
   Port xxx
   Exec to_syslog_ietf();
</Output>
```

Which sends to a syslog-ng server which should catch with the following filter.

```
filter f_iis {
    source ('IIS'); 
};
```

or alternatively I've tried the following.

```
filter f_iis {
    program ('IIS'); 
};
```

Comment: Hi, can you post how a message that syslog-ng receives looks like? Also, how do you transfer the message from nxlog to syslog-ng? RFC3164 or 5428?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are shipping it as plain syslog (i.e. using `to_syslog_bsd()` in `nxlog.conf`) then the value of $SourceName (=`IIS`) will be in the message in the part what RFC3164 calls `TAG`:

```
The value in the TAG field will be the name of the program or
process that generated the message.
```

Syslog-ng calls this `program`, so I believe the second one should do what you need:

```
 filter f_iis {
     program ('IIS'); 
 };
```

Comment: Thanks b0ti. I just came to the same realization. I was using the to_syslog_ietf() option and was always getting a '1' for the program name value.